# How to display database values on mapbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, draw, mapbox-gl-js

I am using Mapbox and I created a database with values like (longitude and latitude), I want to display the data in the form of polygon on my map.

As you can see I want to put the the longitude and latitude from my database to the coordinates on my code but I don't know how to retrieve it from my database.

```
map.on('load', function() {
    map.addSource('maine', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': {
    'type': 'Feature',
    'geometry': {
    'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [

                []
        ]
      }
    }
});
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'maine',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'maine',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
        'fill-color': '#088',
        'fill-opacity': 0.8
        }
     });
 });
```

this is my database which is in the file api.php:
[image: this is my database which is in the file api.php]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to retrieve it from your database either, because you haven't provided any details. But generally speaking, your approach will be:

- provide an API that provides access to the data in some form (such as CSV) via URL (example.com/mydatabase/points.csv)
- fetch the CSV in the client, and transform it to GeoJSON. (If your back end can generate GeoJSON directly, you can save this step)
- add it to the Mapbox map as a GeoJSON source layer